# How to get remaining early start and finish from MPXJ Task object

Tags: mpxj, primavera

I want to get the *remaining early start* and *remaining early finish* properties of an Activity while reading a Primavera *.xer* file. I have seen that the class **PrimaveraPMFileReader** in the mpxj library sets these properties to the task object, but am trying to import xer file and so the reader used is **PrimaveraXERFileReader** class. With the XER reader, the task instances are not set any properties that am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the code of PrimaveraPMFileWriter and also some methods of the [Task](http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/mpxj/Task.html) class of mpxj library, I have realized that to get remaining early start of a task in primavera, you need to use the [getResume()](http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/mpxj/Task.html#getResume()) API of the Task class of mpxj.